# How to smoothly move down in Z-index a curved object

Tags: transforms, bevel

[image: Goal is to gave those red edges]

I'm trying to mode down in z-index this part but in a smoothy way, how to achieve this result ? I easily can do it for a straight line but in this case I really don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blender comes with an add-on called ***Mesh:LoopTools***. Enable it in the *Preferences* then you will see it in the N-panel (<kbd>N</kbd>).

Select the first 2 vertices at the beginning of the ramp and move them down to the floor along the Z-axis.
 Then select the vertices of the edge loop that you want to smooth. Make sure the vertice at the beginning is the active one (selected last, see screenshot).
 After that, use the <kbd>Space</kbd> operation a few times with locked X-axis and Y-axis in the options. Count the number of uses for the other side.

[image]

Repeat the steps for the other side of the ramp. One or two uses of the <kbd>Relax</kbd> operation can smooth out the transition between the ramp and the flat area.

Example:
[image: curved ramp]

Comment: very nice!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

This answer is a slight piggy-back on @Blunder's.. (apologies.) It still uses the shipped add-on *Loop Tools*, but takes advantage of its *Curve* operator to make your slope in one move.

The *Curve* operator depends on selecting vertices in a single, unambiguous, loop of edges. You select the vertices in that loop you would like to remain fixed. The remaining vertices in the loop are then interpolated between them.

Here, the vertices have been selected in Face mode, for speed:

[image]

And *Curve* has been executed on the edge-loop connecting those vertices, interpolating in Z only.

[image]

The tool takes a bit of playing with to get used to the way it works, but it's worth it, IMO. It can be very handy.